# image is not showing on html page

Tags: html

I am new in **Ubuntu**, as well as using **lampp**, My problem is, after storing image in image folder of my apps, image is not showing in HTML file ( image not found ). localhost document root is `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`, and my root folder is **f_21** if I use the following link

```
http://localhost/f_21/index.html    // not works
```

But image showing works well if I use following link:

```
 file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/f_21/index.html  // but it works
```

Any idea ??

Comment: What does "not showing" mean? Do you get an error inside the http servers log file? Do you get an empty page? Does the universe implode? Test what happens if you query that url directly with a browser.

Comment: How are you accessing the html page this is on? Copy and paste what you see in the address bar please.

Comment: Use your browser tools to help debug. press f12 and see whats going wrong...

Comment: "not showing" means that It shows an empty page and not other error.

Comment: Wait is this about an image or an .html page? Did you write the <img src="" path properly?

Comment: I think I write it properly because why it shows image for second link.

Comment: Are you sure that your localhost document root is pointing to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`?

Answer (score 1):

You should keep both image and index.html files under htdocs.

for you,place your index.html and image files under f_21 folder and update src attribute of img tag in your index.html

Answer (score 0):

If the link to the image is an absolute path based on your file system with the `file` protocol, then you won't be able to load it when viewing the html page over http.

Chrome doesn't (I'm not sure about other browsers) allow loading local resources on a file requested with http.

If you're using chrome, you can press ctrl+shift+j to see the console, which will show any errors. You might see something like: `Not allowed to load local resource`.

The solution is to change the `src` of the image to be relative to the html page it's on.